# nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No value for key bound to thread [http-bio-2016-exec-6]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

```
Already value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder@485d518f] for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@29375882] bound to thread [http-bio-2016-exec-6]
No value for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@29375882] bound to thread [http-bio-2016-exec-6]
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "register")

public class Register{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

@Column(name = "uname")
@Size(min = 4, max = 10)
private String uname;

@Column(name = "password")
@Size(min = 4, max = 8)
private String password;

@Column(name = "email")
@NotEmpty
@Email
private String email;

@Column(name = "age")
@NotNull
@Min(10)
@Max(40)
private String age;

@Column(name = "dob")
@NotNull
@Past
private String dob;

@Column(name = "country")
@NotEmpty
private String country;

// setters and getters

public String getUname() {
    System.out.println("control is in getUname method");
    return uname;
}

public void setUname(String uname) {
    System.out.println("control is in getUname method");

    this.uname = uname;
}

public String getEmail() {

    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    System.out.println("control is in getPassword");

    this.email = email;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    System.out.println("control is in setAge method");

    this.age = age;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getDob() {
    return dob;
}

public void setDob(String dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}
```

**Context XML**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring" />
<tx:annotation-driven />

<context:annotation-config />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>


<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usersdb" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="90141139" />
</bean>


<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.spring.model.Register</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="jdbc.fetch_size">20</prop>
            <prop key="jdbc.batch_size">25</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="connection.autoReconnect">true</prop>
            <prop key="connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: please let me know how to slove this issue @Jerin Joseph

Answer (score 1):

I resolved error by using the following annotation on top of my DAO class:

```java
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, re‌​adOnly=false)
```